# Change the color of the icon that hides and displays dashboardControlbar() in shinydashboardPlus()

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can we change the color of the icon in the upper right corner that hides and displays dashboardControlbar() in shinydashboardPlus()?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar()
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          "[data-toggle=control-sidebar] {
            color: red !important;
          }"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar()
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I meant the dashboardControlbar toggle in the right , not the left one